# How can you use both fontspec and xmpincl?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, fontspec, xmp

Is there a way to use both the `fontspec` and the `xmpincl` packages? Using PDFTeX returns

> Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
>
> The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
>
> You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"

XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX returns

> Package xmpincl Error: latex is not supported by the \includexmp package.

Comment: My earlier comment was misleading, as karlkoeller's answer shows. (So I deleted it.)  However, the point about `hyperxmp` being more flexible in terms of how you construct the document remains true, and the same goes for its being more user-friendly at the cost of being somewhat less flexible in terms of what you can include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excluding `pdflatex`, which is not an option since it cannot be used together with `fontspec`, let's try to understand whether `xelatex` or `lualatex` can be used.

The file `xmpincl.sty` contains the following lines:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\else
\PackageWarningNoLine{xmpincl}%
  {Only pdflatex is supported by the xmpincl package}
\newcommand{\includexmp}[1]{%
  \PackageError{xmpincl}%
  {latex is not supported by the \protect\includexmp\space package}%
  {You tried to include XMP metadata in DVI production.\MessageBreak
   That doesn't work, and I friendly tried to warn you.\MessageBreak
   Just continue and pretend nothing is wrong,\MessageBreak
   but please remove the package or switch to pdflatex.}
}
\relax\expandafter\endinput
\fi
```

This means that it returns an error when you use `\includexmp` if the `\ifpdf` test is false.

You can use the following minimal file to test whether `\ifpdf` returns true or false

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\begin{document}
\ifpdf
\texttt{xmpincl} can be used
\else
\texttt{xmpincl} cannot be used
\fi
\end{document}
```

With `lualatex` (beta-0.76.0-2013062820) I get

[image]

while with `xelatex` (3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3) I get

[image]

This means that with an up-to-date `luatex` engine you should be able to use `fontspec` together with `xmpincl`.

Comment: Does LuaTeX have the appropriate primitives for `xmpincl`?

Comment: @JosephWright Well, I don't know. I've never used it. I just tried to see if the package issues the error when using LuaTeX.

Comment: Hmm, I think this looks OK: the primitives needed seem to be ones retained in LuaTeX (`\pdfobj`, `\pdfcatalog`, `\pdflastobj`).

Comment: Well, I've deleted my comment as the 'never, unless extended' claim was at least partially wrong!  +1 for testing....